# When i login with google using firebase it only shows the users information on the next page when i click on ctrl+save. It does not reloads page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have this simple flutter app in which I am simply using login and logout functioanlities with google using firebase, **everything is working fine**, but only problem i am facing is When i login, it only shows the information of user on the next page **WHEN** i click on **ctrl+save**. It renders to the logged in page but does not shows the user information like email, name and picture.
Please help me out, I am stuck in it since days.

Here is my **google_sign_in.dart** file in which I have defined the function of GoogleLogin and Logout functions:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final googleSign = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user; // this is where we will save the information of our save

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;   // using get method to get that google account

  Future GoogleLogin() async {
    final googleUser = await googleSign.signIn(); // this will make sure that the popup appears showing the different ids to sign in
    if (googleUser == null) return; // this will make sure that user has selected an account
    _user = googleUser; // if he has selected an account, we will save it in _user.

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication; // next we are calling on our google user that we have fetched.

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential); // now we are using the above credential to sign in firebase_auth

    notifyListeners();  // to update the UI
  }

  Future logout() async{
    await googleSign.disconnect();  // disconnecting the googleSignin that we created initially.
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();  // signing out from the firebase.
  }
}
```

This is my **homePage.dart**:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/sign_up_page.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/logged_in_widget.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(), // Every time user signs in or signs out, the below widget will get updated.
      builder: (context, snapshot) {  // accessing the user information in the snapshot.
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return LoggedInWidget();
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong!'),);
        } else {
          return SignUpWidget();
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

My **signUp Widget** in **sign_up_page.dart** file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/logged_in_widget.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/sign_up_page.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/google_sign_in.dart';


class SignUpWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpWidgetState createState() => _SignUpWidgetState();
}

class _SignUpWidgetState extends State<SignUpWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Spacer(),
          FlutterLogo(size: 120),
          Spacer(),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
                provider.GoogleLogin();
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoggedInWidget()),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Sign in with Google')
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my **LoggedInWidget** where I am showing all the user information in **logged_in_widget.dart**:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:yt_firebase2/sign_up_page.dart';


class LoggedInWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Logged In'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final provider = Provider.of<GoogleSignInProvider>(context, listen: false);
                provider.logout();
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpWidget()),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Logout'),)
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('profile', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
              SizedBox(height: 32,),
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 40,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user?.photoURL ?? ""),

              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8,),
              Text(
                'Name:' + (user?.displayName ?? ""),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8,),
              Text(
                'Email:' + (user?.email ?? ""),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```